# React useContext accessing only required value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm tried to access only few values in my component but have to define all the values in useContext. if a am not defining the sequence its giving error

```
const [handleChange, isEditMode, setIsEditMode, partnerData, setPartnerData] = useContext(FilterContext);
```

here i want to use only two elements isEditmode and PartnerData

Answer (score 0):

Create the context as an object and use curly braces to get just one property of it.

```
const FilterContext = createContext({
  handleChange: function (...) {...},
  isEditMode: false,
  setIsEditMode: function (...) {...},
  partnerData: function (...) {...},
  setPartnerData: function (...) {...}
})

const { isEditmode, partnerData } = useContext(FilterContext)
```

Comment: Is this right for current main question?

Comment: @DavidTeo Yes, it just uses other names. I adapted it to the names of context and properties in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [handleChange, isEditMode, setIsEditMode, partnerData, setPartnerData] = useContext(FilterContext);
```

You can use [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const [, isEditMode, ,partnerData] = useContext(FilterContext);
```